# jquery+svg: how to position text on top of circle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I draw a circle using svg jquery

```
_svg.circle(_X, _Y, _R, { fill: 'yellow', stroke: 'black', strokeWidth: 1 });
```

On top of it I want to put a text:

```
var _svgGroup = _svg.group({ fontSize: '11', fill: 'black' });
_svg.text(_svgGroup, _X, _Y + 15, "#");
```

The problem is that text is always "underneath" the circle and it partially not visible.

How can I bring text on top of circle? Is there something like z-order in svg?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code works:

```
var _svgTextStyle = { fontSize: '11', fill: 'red' };
var _svgCircleStyle = { fill: 'yellow', stroke: 'black', strokeWidth: 1 };
_svg.circle(pos.getPosX() + 7, pos.getPosY() + 0, 7, _svgCircleStyle);
_svg.text(pos.getPosX() + 0, pos.getPosY() + 10, pos.getId() + "", _svgTextStyle);
```

So the difference is that style should be passed not as 'group' object in a 1st parameter, but as a pure array in 4th.

Dunno actually, why "group" doesn't work as I see reference that recommended it.

Answer (score 1):

When i tried with the same kind of code, it works fine.

My code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#svgbasics').svg({onLoad: drawInitial});
    function drawInitial(svg) {
        var _X = 200;
        var _Y = 200;
        var _Z = 100;
        svg.circle(_X, _Y, _Z, { fill: 'yellow', stroke: 'black', strokeWidth: 1 });
        var _svgGroup = svg.group({ fontSize: '11', fill: 'black' });
        svg.text(_X, _Y + 15, "Hello World");
    }
});
```

Also, before the code we may need to include the piece of css.

```
<style type="text/css">
@import "jquery.svg.css";
#svgbasics { width: 400px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid #484; }
</style>
```

I got this from the sample files (svgBasic.html) present inside the jquery.svg library.

Comment: Thank you for help, you example helped me to find out the place of concern, will post it in another answer in few minutes

Comment: In fact, you have a small mistake in your code: _svgGroup is defined, but not used. And IF it is used, it will prevent text to be displayed on top of the circle... In fact, the same mistake is in my original question