# How to adjust size of graph node to fit text when using dracula?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am using [dracula](http://www.graphdracula.net/) for visualizing some graphs. This is a sample html page using dracula:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>
            Testing Dracula
        </title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/vendor/dracula/raphael-min.js">

        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/vendor/dracula/dracula_graph.js">

        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/vendor/dracula/dracula_graffle.js">

        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/vendor/jquery.min.js">

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id='canvas'>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          var render = function(r, n) {
          var set = r.set().push(
          r.rect(n.point[0] - 30, n.point[1] - 13, 62, 86).attr({
                             "fill": "#fa8",
                             "stroke-width": 2,
                              r: "9px"
          })).push(r.text(n.point[0], n.point[1] + 30, n.label).attr({
                                   "font-size": "14px"
              })); /* custom tooltip attached to the set */
          set.items.forEach(
               function(el) {
                  el.tooltip(r.set().push(r.rect(0, 0, 0, 0).attr({
                                     "fill": "#fec",
                                     "stroke-width": 1,
                                     r: "9px"
                   })))
               });
          return set;
          };

          $(document).ready(function() {
             var width = $(document).width() - 20;
             var height = $(document).height() - 60;
             var g = new Graph();
             var data = {
               "vertices": ["This is some sample long text.", "A", "B", "C", "D\n some More Sample\n Text", "E"],
               "edges": [
                          [
                           0, 1],
                          [
                           0, 2],
                          [
                           0, 3],
                          [
                           2, 4],
                          [
                           3, 4],
                          [
                           4, 5]
                         ]
            };


            addNodes(data.vertices, g);
            addEdges(data.edges, g);

            var layouter = new Graph.Layout.Spring(g);
            layouter.layout(); /* draw the graph using the RaphaelJS draw implementation */
            var renderer = new Graph.Renderer.Raphael('canvas', g, width, height);
                                       renderer.draw();

                               });

            function addNodes(vertices, g) {
                jQuery.each(vertices, function(index, text) {
                g.addNode(index, {
                     label: text,
                     render: render
                             });
                           });
                               }
                 function addEdges(edges, g) {
                 jQuery.each(edges, function(index, arr) {
                 g.addEdge(arr[0], arr[1], {
                      directed: true
                   })
                 });
                               }
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

As you can see in the image below, lengthier text in the node flows outside the bounding box. How can I create node so that its dimensions are large enough to fit the contents within its bounds?

[image: Sample Dracula Graph]

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track here.  You can do this in your rendering function.  First you add your text element, figure out it's width, use that width when creating the box, then moving the text element to be after the box element.  [Here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566406/svg-re-ordering-z-index-raphael-optional) that fourth step is necessary.

You might modify your code to something like this:

```
var render = function(r, n) {
    var set = r.set().push(
    var textbit = r.text(n.point[0], n.point[1] + 30, n.label).attr({ "font-size": "14px" });
    var width = $(textbit.node).width() + 10 ;
    textbit.remove();
        r.rect(n.point[0] - Math.round(width / 2), n.point[1] - 13, width, 86).attr({
                     "fill": "#fa8",
                     "stroke-width": 2,
                      r: "9px"
    })).push(r.text(n.point[0], n.point[1] + 30, n.label).attr({
                           "font-size": "14px"
      })); /* custom tooltip attached to the set */
    set.items.forEach(
       function(el) {
          el.tooltip(r.set().push(r.rect(0, 0, 0, 0).attr({
                             "fill": "#fec",
                             "stroke-width": 1,
                             r: "9px"
           })))
       });
    return set;
};
```

Granted, in this example I'm not actually moving the text element to the back of the DOM, but rather creating a "test" version of the text first just to get the width, then I remove it.  Simply moving the element might end up being faster (and perhaps a bit more elegant) but this works

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve it in this way.
I added my own render function for this case which handles the size of node on basis of text/label of node.

```
 var render = function (r, n) {
      var frame = r.rect(n.point[0] - 3*n.label.length, n.point[1] - 3, 6*n.label.length, 25);
      frame.attr({
          fill: n.Color, r: n.Radius,
          'stroke-width': (n.distance+'px')
      });
      /* the Raphael set is obligatory, containing all you want to display */
      var set = r.set().push(frame,
          /* custom objects go here */
          r.text(n.point[0], n.point[1] + 10,n.label)
      );
      return set;
  };
```

This will be dependent on your font size but the formula will remain same.