# Z-order and z-index in SVG for particular group or element

Tags: svg, jquery-svg

i drawn one line in SVG using "path" tag and then i drawn circle on the same x value of line but the circle is behind the line. i want the circle element in front of line. how to set z-order or z-index to particular group or element in svg to display the element in front.

i tried z-Index attribute to circle but its not working .

```
<circle  .... z-Index=1000>

</circle>
```

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: [You'll need to change the order of the elements in the SVG content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566406/svg-re-ordering-z-index-raphael-optional).  (Link includes example code.)

Answer (score 3):

SVG elements do not have a z-index that you can adjust. Their layering order is dependent on what order you draw them in the HTML. Moving an SVG object to the top, for example, is a matter of removing it from the DOM and appending it to the object's parent. Since it is the most recently drawn SVG object, it will therefore be shown on top.