# x-area labels on hover

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need add another color for xAxis labels when it's hover ([like number 19 in the picture](http://librifolio.ru/analytics_earnings.jpg)). I saw this property later but I lost it.

Need a help =)

And can I set a property (z-index) for xAxis tick? Cause its color must be white, and now I can't see this color, when its z-index less than z-index chart's area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, I would use a shared tooltip and the `point mouseOver` event to change the corresponding axis label:

```
   plotOptions: {
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    // on mouseOver make the xaxis label red
                    mouseOver: function(){
                        var xAxis = this.series.chart.xAxis[0];
                        $(xAxis.ticks[this.x].label.element).css('fill','red');
                    },
                    // on mouseOut make it gray again
                    mouseOut: function(){
                        var xAxis = this.series.chart.xAxis[0];
                        $(xAxis.ticks[this.x].label.element).css('fill','#606060');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z4jxqhra/).

For your second question, z index with SVG is a [little](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331101/z-order-and-z-index-in-svg-for-particular-group-or-element) [tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566406/svg-re-ordering-z-index-raphael-optional).  It doesn't have a true zIndex you can re-order but rather it's dictated by the order in which the elements are drawn.  I can't see it matters, though, because the labels are drawn on top of the chart area already (or else you wouldn't see them at all).

Comment: Thank U! But I thought there is some another propertys, another way... to specify these settings.
It's my first question, and it's success!