# AmChart bullets stack order

Tags: javascript, graph, amcharts

How can I change the stack order of the graph's bullets? I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vgc3352L/) example and `Africa`'s bullet is over `Middle-East`'s bullet and it's not looks round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply change it by properties. AmCharts renders the SVG in a strict order, and the z-index for a SVG element is defined by its appearing index in the DOM tree.
Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566406/svg-re-ordering-z-index-raphael-optional).