# How do I adjust the "depth" of graphics in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graphics, overlap, depth

I am writing an animation using d3, and I cannot seem to find a way to easily ensure that a graphic always appears "behind" other graphics.

Specifically, I am dealing with lines and circles (imagine a directed graph), and it sort of looks bad to have some of the lines on top of the circles, and others underneath. Is there a way to set the z/depth of certain graphics, in this case my lines, manually? I apologize if this seems google-able, but I attempted typing "graphic depth d3" and other variations and got nothing.

EDIT : Accepted answer works, a more detailed description of the problem can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595175/updating-svg-element-z-index-with-d3).

Comment: Maybe the following SO question helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595175/updating-svg-element-z-index-with-d3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVG doesn't have a `z-index` property or similar, the elements are drawn in the order in which they appear in the DOM -- elements higher up are drawn behind elements that have been added afterwards.

The easiest way to group elements into layers is to use `g` elements. So in your example, I would use two `g` groups, one for the lines and one for the circles. Add the `g` for the lines first and then all of the lines underneath it. If you then add the circles to the second `g` that you added afterwards, all circles will always be on top of all lines.

Comment: Alright, that seems to be the way to do things. Lemme get a mockup really quick and then I'll give you the accepted answer.

Comment: Worked as expected. Thanks for the knowledge re-direct.