# d3.js mouseover overlapping circles

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am currently trying to solve a problem with overlapping circles where some larger circles prevent the mouseover event on smaller ones. Here is what I have so far to demonstrate the problem: http://bl.ocks.org/lilyc5459/raw/a35687613ab0f4991f37/

The code can be found here: http://bl.ocks.org/lilyc5459/a35687613ab0f4991f37

Any ideas as to how to solve this is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: How would you like the graphic to behave?  If one circle overlaps another, you need a well-defined decision rule that decides which circle will be 'mouseovered'.

Comment: Have a look at these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595175/updating-svg-element-z-index-with-d3, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167863/how-can-i-bring-a-circle-to-the-front-with-d3

Comment: @RobinL: essentially, I would like the smaller circles to always be in front of the larger ones so it can be moused over.

Comment: @dekkard: thanks! I will check those out!

Comment: Try sorting the elements by size before drawing perhaps?

Comment: @RobinL: that totally did it. I should have thought of that haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should sort the received data by `padeedits` field in descending order, so the bigger circles are inserted before smaller and there won't be any overlapping more.

So modify your code this way:

```
  ...
  svg.selectAll(".loading").remove();

  // code block for inserting

  data.sort(function(a,b) {
    if (a.pageedits > b.pageedits)
      return -1;
    if (a.pageedits < b.pageedits)
      return 1;
    return 0;
  });

  // end of block

  svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle") 
  ...
```

Comment: It is a solution that works, although we might occasionally like to keep an item visually on top while still firing off the event