# parentNode in d3 svg

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, parent

I've used an example [snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/Q5Jag/1194/), cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595175/updating-svg-element-z-index-with-d3), to get to the parent node of a svg element, but I obtain `undefined`. Why? And How to correct it?

```
var svg = d3.select('svg');

var lbl=    svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", 10)
        .attr("y", 110)
        .text("aaaaa");

alert(lbl.parentNode);
```

(JSFiddle version [here](https://jsfiddle.net/h3m5bLps/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lbl is still a d3 selection, to do .parentNode you need to get the DOM node for lbl first

```
alert(lbl.node().parentNode);
```