# Append SVG items on top of existing elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, visualization

I'm trying to add points to a map using the `d3.js` library.
(I've tried to adapt a script from this [gist](http://bl.ocks.org/abenrob/c4ac3d581a7b16ff5f2f)).

The problem is that the map is being rendered on top of the dots.
I've tried to use another SO answer which suggested something like this: 
`svg.append("g").attr("id", "map").attr("id", "points")`...but I have been unable to make it work. I'm a long time python user...JavaScript is new for me (so please excuse the naivety).

Am using the following CSS:

```
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: white;
    }
    svg {
        border: 1px solid black;
        background-color: #a4bac7;
    }
        .land {
          fill: #d7c7ad;
          stroke: #8999ab;
        }
        .boundary {
          fill: none;
          stroke: #a5967f;
        }
  </style>
```

Body:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v0.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var width = 960;
        var height = 480;
        var dataURL = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/abenrob/787723ca91772591b47e/raw/8a7f176072d508218e120773943b595c998991be/world-50m.json";

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);
```

---

In response to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17133220) SO answer answer, added this:

```
        svg.append("g")
                .attr("id", "map")
                .attr("id", "points");
```

---

```
        var projection = d3.geoEquirectangular()
            .scale(153)
            .translate([width/2,height/2])

        var path = d3.geoPath()
            .projection(projection);

        d3.json(dataURL, function(error, world) {
            svg.append("g")
                .select("#map").selectAll(".map")
                .attr("class", "land")
                .selectAll("path")
                .data([topojson.object(world, world.objects.land)])
                .enter().append("path")
                .attr("d", path);
            svg.append("g")
                .select("#map").selectAll(".map")
                .attr("class", "boundary")
                .selectAll("boundary")
                .data([topojson.object(world, world.objects.countries)])
                .enter().append("path")
                .attr("d", path);
            }
        );

        var lngLatExtract = function(d, i){
            return projection([d['lng'], d['lat']])[i];
        };

        d3.csv("cities.csv", function(data){
                svg.append("g")
                        .select("#points").selectAll(".points")
                        .data(data)
                        .enter()
                            .append('circle')
                            .attr("cx", function(d){
                                return lngLatExtract(d, 0);
                            })
                            .attr('cy', function(d){
                                return lngLatExtract(d, 1);
                            })
                            .style("fill", "blue")
                            .style("opacity", 0.75)
                            .attr("r", function(d){
                                return Math.sqrt(parseInt(d['population']) * 0.000001)
                            });
                }
        );

    </script>
```

`cities.csv` looks like this:

```
rank,place,population,lat,lng
1,New York city,8175133,40.71455,-74.007124
2,Los Angeles city,3792621,34.05349,-118.245323
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `d3.json` and `d3.csv` are *async* functions.  The order in which their callbacks fire is not a given and in fact since your csv file is smaller, it's callback is probably firing first.  That means that your `svg.append("g")` in your csv callback is happening **before** the `svg.append("g")` in the json callback.  You can confirm this by inspecting the DOM and to see which was appended first.

That said, I would switch to using [d3.queue](https://github.com/d3/d3-queue).  This allows you to fire off both the `d3.json` and `d3.csv` async requests and then fire a single callback with both are complete.

Another less streamlined option is to place your `d3.csv` code in the callback of the `d3.json` call.