# How can I bring a circle to the front with d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

First of all, I am using d3.js to display different sized circles in arrays. On mouse over, I want the circle being moused over to become bigger, which I can do, but I have no idea how to bring it to the front. Currently, once it's rendered, it's hidden behind multiple other circles. How can I fix this?

Here's a code sample:

```
   .on("mouseover", function() { 
    d3.select(this).attr("r", function(d) { return 100; })
  })
```

I tried using the sort and order methods, but they didn't work. I'm pretty sure i didn't do it correctly. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm still new to d3.js, but I think you should be able to accomplish this by hiding/showing the element in order to re-render it?

Comment: From this post it seems that re-appending the element to the svg has this effect.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482115/with-javascript-can-i-change-the-z-index-layer-of-an-svg-g-element

Comment: It's not working for me :\

Comment: Mike demonstrated a few of ways of doing this in this thread: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/d3-js/OqD9_puVTfg/aMDYbGHB2fAJ

Comment: d3.selection.prototype.moveToFront = function() { 
    return this.each(function() { 
      this.parentNode.appendChild(this); 
    }); 
  }; 

And then you can say selection.moveToFront().

Comment: See how Ian uses this method in this tributary entry: http://enjalot.com/tributary/3651456/

Comment: [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/Lq4zd/3/) using the moveToFront approach.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

**TL;DR**

With latest versions of D3, you can use `selection.raise()` as explained by [tmpearce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1214731/tmpearce) in [its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42673158/1041692). Please scroll down and upvote!

---

**Original answer**

You will have to change the order of object and make the circle you mouseover being the last element added. As you can see here: https://gist.github.com/3922684 and as suggested by [nautat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/760156/nautat), you have to define the following before your main script:

```
d3.selection.prototype.moveToFront = function() {
  return this.each(function(){
    this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
  });
};
```

Then you will just have to call the `moveToFront` function on your object (say `circles`) on mouseover:

```
circles.on("mouseover",function(){
  var sel = d3.select(this);
  sel.moveToFront();
});
```

**Edit:** As suggested by [Henrik Nordberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1798937/henrik-nordberg) it is necessary to bind the data to the DOM by using the second argument of the `.data()`. This is necessary to not lose binding on elements. Please read Henrick's answer (and upvote it!) for more info. As a general advice, always use the second argument of `.data()` when binding data to the DOM in order to leverage the full performance capabilities of d3.

---

**Edit:**
As mentioned by [Clemens Tolboom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/598513/clemens-tolboom), the reverse function would be:

```
d3.selection.prototype.moveToBack = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var firstChild = this.parentNode.firstChild;
        if (firstChild) {
            this.parentNode.insertBefore(this, firstChild);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: I needed the reverse too: this is what I did: `d3.selection.prototype.moveToBack = function() { return this.each(function() { var firstChild = this.parentNode.firstChild; if (firstChild) { this.parentNode.insertBefore(this, firstChild); } }); };`

Comment: See @Henrik Nordberg answer below. Your data will get out of sync doing this

Comment: Hi @christopher Chiche, I tried your solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33000725/how-to-position-nvd3-line-graph-above-all-other-area-bar-graphs but still can't get the positions of the line graph to change. Thoughts?

Comment: doesnt work in IE if you have other event handlers on node getting moved... they get dropped

Answer (score 38):

As of d3 version 4, there are a set of built in functions that handle this type of behavior without needing to implement it yourself.  See the [d3v4 documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#modifying-elements) for more info.

Long story short, to bring an element to the front, use `selection.raise()`

> #### selection.raise()
>
> Re-inserts each selected element, in order, as the last child of its parent. Equivalent to:
>
> `selection.each(function() {`  
>  `this.parentNode.appendChild(this);` 
>  `});`

Answer (score 25):

If you use the `moveToFront()` method, make sure you are specifying the second argument to the `data()` join method, or your data will be out of synch with your DOM.

d3.js joins your data (provided to a `parse()`) method with DOM elements you create. If you manipulate the DOM as proposed above, d3.js won't know what DOM element corresponds to what data 'point' unless you specify a unique value for each data 'point' in the `data()` call as the [API reference](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data) shows:

`.data(data, function(d) { return d.name; })`

Comment: can you elaborate .. which data to pass ?

Comment: @DavidWilton better late than never, I have added a reference to this answer in my answer.

Answer (score 13):

From my painful experience with IE9, using parentNode.appendChild may lead to lost event handlers in the nodes. So I tend to use another approach, that is, sorting the nodes so that the selected one is above the others:

```
     .on("mouseover", function(selected) {
        vis.selectAll('.node')
        .sort(function(a, b) {
          if (a.id === selected.id) {
            return 1;
          } else {
            if (b.id === selected.id) {
              return -1;
            } else {
              return 0;
            }
          }
        });
      })
```

Comment: can you elaborate here a little bit.. what is vis in your code. And is 'node' a class of your svg elements? I am running into the same issue on IE

Comment: vis is a D3 selection of the parent element containing the elements which you want to reorder. 'node' is the CSS class which these elements should have.

Comment: terser sorting function : `function(a,b) {s = selected.id; return (a.id == s) - (b.id == s);}`

Comment: Great solution for IE9.

Comment: how do I get a reference to `vis` from outside the mouseover event?  I'm trying to find `vis` inside the `dragstart` event but I can't find it anywhere.  `this` references the element that I want to bring to the top.