# D3-tip behind graph when in modal

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

This is my first attempt with d3.js and I am having small problem with the d3-tip function. A picture is worth a thousand words so here is my issue.

[image]

d3-tips were working fine until I put my graph inside of a modal. I have tried css z-index as part of the d3-tip style:

```
 .d3-tip {
        line-height: 1;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 12px;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 2px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

This didn't have any effect and in my limited css knowledge I think that the z-index is still using my main body as the relational key.

Here is my `var tip` setup:

```
       var tip = d3.tip()
           .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
           .offset([-10, 0])
           .html(function(d) {
             return "<strong>Date:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.date + "</span></br><strong>Time:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.time + "</span>
                        </br><strong>Around:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.timeGroup + "</span>";
        });
```

Here is my modal:

```
 <div id="modal-barGraph" class="modal flex-child fade" role='dialog'>
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <button class="close white" aria-hidden='' data-dismiss="modal" type="button">X</button>
        <div id="barGraph" ></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I have also tried following the suggestions on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167863/how-can-i-bring-a-circle-to-the-front-with-d3).

Is there any way to bring the tip to front with my current setup? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to set z-index: 10000 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the current `css` `z-index` to `z-index: 10000`

The `modal` has a value greater than 1 (the default is 1050) , therefore you wouldn't see it with the current `css`.