# d3 svg bring to front in IE

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

A solution is offered in various places, including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167863/how-can-i-bring-a-circle-to-the-front-with-d3) and it works fine in Firefox and Chrome.  But it breaks in IE (I'm using IE 11).

The basic idea is to do this in the `mouseover` listener

```
    this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
```

Since a node can only have one parent, the original reference is deleted before re-appending at the end of the child nodes.

Normally the `mouseover` event only fires once on initial `mouseover`, but, the `append` seems to reset the event for the element in IE so the event fires again on the next `mousemove`.  This causes the `mouseover` event to behave like `mousemove` and also stops mouseout from working.

In IE there are no `mouseout` events reported

It can be fixed by fiddling around removing the event from the element first and then re-attaching it after a timeout, but is there another way?

```js
(function () {
 d3.selection.prototype.moveToFront = function () {
  return this.each(function () {
   this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
  });
 };

 var log = d3.select('#output'), counter = 0

 var svg = d3.select("body").append('svg');

 var data = d3.range(10);

 var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .append("circle")
   .attr({
    cx: function (d, i) { return d * 20 + 100 },
    cy: 50,
    r: 20,
    fill: "#aaa",
    stroke: "#000"
   })
   .on("mouseover", function () {
    var sel = d3.select(this);
    sel.moveToFront();
    logEvent();
   })
   .on("mouseout", logEvent);
 function logEvent() {
  var e = d3.event, node,
    message = counter++ + ' ' + e.type + ': ' + e.target.tagName + ' ---> ' + e.currentTarget.tagName
  console.log(message)
  node = log.html(log.html() + '<p class="' + e.type + '">' + message + '</p>').node();
  node.scrollTop = node.scrollHeight;
 }
})()
```

```css
#output {
      height: 100px;
      overflow:scroll;
    }
    p {
      margin:0;
    }
    .mouseover {
      color: red;
    }
    .mouseout {
      color: green;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
  <div id="output"></div>
```