# Trouble with Getting SVG to Come to the Front with D3 Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

How do you get an SVG to come to the front in Javascript?  The answer is to use D3 [moveToFront()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167863/how-can-i-bring-a-circle-to-the-front-with-d3) or try adding a [script to the html](http://www.adamwadeharris.com/how-to-bring-svg-elements-to-the-front/) like the following:

```
[<script>
  d3.selectAll('circle').on('mouseenter', function() {
    this.parentElement.appendChild(this);
  });
</script>][2]
```

However, I try to get the SVG to show it never works.  Now I know the SVG element is created because it appears in developer mode on the click event, .  It is also the last element on that list.  Thank you.

Here's a Fiddle, so you can see what I'm talking about.
https://jsfiddle.net/Math8Gr/fzpqdkwg/

This is the code in question:

```
  $('div.cell').click(function() {
  //create SVG
  var point = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
  //set attributes
  point.setAttribute('cx', 100);
  point.setAttribute('cy', 75);
  point.setAttribute('r', 8);
  point.setAttribute('fill', 'red');
  //Add to parent node
  document.getElementById('grid').appendChild(point, function() {
    var sel = d3.select(point);
    sel.moveToFront();
  });
```

Comment: You combine there svg elements with regular html elements... are you sure you know what you are doing?

Comment: I have no clue, I learned to code with a few crash courses from Codecademy.

Comment: I'm sure that even at Codecademy they teach that SVG elements should go inside `<svg>...</svg>` container :)

Comment: I guess i'll stick to the back of cereal boxes then lol.  Usually, I try to figure things out with a couple of searches here.  When that doesn't work, I try random "stuff" and then create a post.

Comment: I tried changing the tags to <svg> and </svg>, no luck.

Comment: I'm not sure which tags you changed, but the entire structure is wrong. You can't put `<div>` inside your `<svg>`, and you can't put `<circle>` inside `<div>`...

Comment: Okay, then append SVG directly to the document: document.parentElement.appendChild(point);