# Highcharts 3.0 - Renderer is covering the export button

Tags: highcharts

I just upgraded an application to Highcharts 3.0, and it looks like the new export button is now covered by objects drawn using the chart renderer.  This wasn't the case under 2.3.3.

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/YcJ6U/1/

Here's the code to produce the plot:

$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

```
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function(event) {
                drawBox(this);
            }
        }
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    }],

    exporting: {
        buttons: {
            contextButton: {
                symbol: 'circle',
                symbolStrokeWidth: 1,
                symbolFill: '#bada55',
                symbolStroke: '#330033',
                align: 'left'
            }
        }
    }

}, function(chart) {
    //drawBox(chart)
});

function drawBox(chart) {
    chart.renderer.rect(25, 0, 100, 100, 5)
        .attr({
            'stroke-width': 2,
            stroke: 'red',
            fill: 'yellow'               
        }).add();        
}
```

});
Can anyone provide a solution to this?

Comment: If you set the `renderers` zIndex to 3, you put it on top the button.  Remove that line and problem solved..

Comment: You're right, that's what I get for copying and pasting.  I updated the fiddle to demonstrate the behavior regardless of removing zIndex: http://jsfiddle.net/YcJ6U/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure when this changed but Highcharts is rendering both the button and the rect using SVG.  Element stacking order is based on the [order they were drawn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/482147/16363).  By drawing the `rect` onload, you are drawing it after the button.  I believe the only way to fix this would be after the chart is drawn to bring the button back to the top:

```
chart.exportSVGElements[0].toFront()
```

Or go back to how it was in the initial link without the zIndex :)

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YcJ6U/2/).

Comment: Awesome, bringing it to the front took care of it.  I feel like this should probably be considered a bug (why would someone enable exporting just to draw a canvas element over it?).  I also think the draw order shouldn't be affected by which method a user employs to perform actions on chart complete.  Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

that is maybe a z-index problem. in highcharts z-index represents by zIndex. 
you should try this

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        contextButton: {
            theme: {
                 zIndex: 10
             }
        }
    }
}
```

hey this is works. i checked it

Comment: Thanks. As of 2018, this is no longer documented by Highcharts, but worked well enough for me, too.

Answer (score 0):

With highchart 6.0.4:

```
   exporting: {
                buttons: {
                    contextButton: {
                        theme: {
                            style: {
                                zIndex: 9999
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
  }
```