# D3 js line overlaps node

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I am doing force layout, on event click i add new node and connect by line. But
line overlaps node. Why? My code is shown http://jsfiddle.net/WRGtL/

```
function click(d) {
  if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; // ignore drag
  //alert("clicked");
  var d = {id:"d"};
  nodes.push(nodeId[index]);
  if(index==0)
  links.push({source: a, target: nodeId[index]});
      else
      links.push({source: nodes[1], target: nodeId[index]});
  index++;
  start();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SVG, the [Z order of elements is the order they appear in the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482115/with-javascript-can-i-change-the-z-index-layer-of-an-svg-g-element/482147#482147). The easiest way of having all lines appear below the circles is to group all lines and all circles in their own groups and let these groups define the Z order.

I've simply added two groups `linksG` and `nodesG` that the elements will be created in:

```
var linkG = svg.append("g"),
    nodeG = svg.append("g");

var node = nodeG.selectAll(".node"),
    link = linkG.selectAll(".link");
```

see the [<kbd>**JSFiddle**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/R6CQM/1/) for a demo.

Edit: forgot to save the fiddle. Link fixed.