# D3 bar chart bar text labels not visible properly

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a stacked bar chart in d3.js 
For every stacked bar i have corresponding text value showing near stack itself.
problem is, some text values displaying are hidden behind bars, where as some are visible over bars. I want all text to visible over my bars. my code looks like,

```
bar.append("text")
.attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.x); })
.attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); })
 .attr("dy", ".35em")
 .attr('style', 'font-size:13px')
 .text(function (d) { if (d.y != 0) { return "$" + d.y; } })
 .style('fill', 'black');
```

Comment: Provide an example please (e.g. on jsfiddle).

Comment: Where is bar chart and text  in the fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the issue related to z-index. But there is no z-index for SVG, so it can be fixed by reordering elements. Details here [With JavaScript, can I change the Z index/layer of an SVG <g> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482115/with-javascript-can-i-change-the-z-index-layer-of-an-svg-g-element/482147#482147)

**The simplest and fastest way:**

To add `.reverse()` to the dataset.

```
// Create groups for each series, rects for each segment 
var groups = svg.selectAll("g.cost")
    .data(dataset.reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "cost")
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors[i]; });
```

**The better way**

To add different containers for bars and labels and put them in the right order in the DOM.

Try it http://jsfiddle.net/kashesandr/z90aywdj/

Comment: I have tried it.. Its working in many labels, one or two still as before, not completely visible

Comment: Okay, basically the problem in z-index as I wrote before (see comments here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482115/with-javascript-can-i-change-the-z-index-layer-of-an-svg-g-element/482147#482147). So, here we have to change the order of elements to support what you need.

Comment: I'll try to reorder them today, but not sure will have enough time. Try it by yourself.